# Resizing DIV Panel

Tags: jquery, resizable

I am working on a website project and I need to add a **resizable** panel like jsfiddle or hotmail (hotmail has a left panel that includes your mails, and has a right content panel that you can read your mails...)

I looked at jQuery and I tried so many times but I can't set the **handler**. I just need to make a panel that can be resizable horizontally.

So how can I make this? Can you help me to complete my code (need a resizer  between the left_panel and content. Resizer will resize the left_panel and of course **content will be effected.**)

```
> http://jsfiddle.net/QkZL8
```

Comment: what do you mean with **resizable**

Comment: It's a jQuery UI feature to make DOM elements resizable by a user.

Comment: @AndreaTurri I mean, I want to make a interface like hotmail. Do you have hotmail acc? If you, you can understand what I wanted to say. Or you haven't you can look jsfiddle's resizable panels (html, css, java, result)
 thanks..

Comment: @JeroenMoons , What is the different between the JQuery UI or JQuery? Can you complete my code in jsfiddle ? Thanks.. http://jsfiddle.net/QkZL8/

Comment: jQuery UI is an extension/plugin for jQuery adding functionality to do certain GUI tasks like resizing, drag and drop, and gui elements like sliders etc. These things are not part of jQuery itself and jQuery UI needs to be added if you want to use any of its features.

Comment: @JeroenMoons I got it. Thank you. I'll add jquery and I hope It'll work.
Edit: I add It but still I can't resize my <div>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The fiddle doesn't work because jQuery UI isn't included (so jQuery UI resizable is not known), but also you made a syntax error, you should do this:

```
$(resize).resizable({
    handles: 'w'
});
```

not this:

```
$(resize).resizable({,,
    handles: 'w', 
});
```

As David remarks in the comments, you should make the panel itself resizable, not an in between splitter element. In the resize handler you can resize the other panel so its width is complementary to the width of the panel you are actually resizing.

**UPDATE**: This should put you on the right track:

```
$(resize).resizable({
    // only use the eastern handle
    handles: 'e',
    // restrict the width range
    minWidth: 120,
    maxWidth: 450,
    // resize handler updates the content panel width
    resize: function(event, ui){
        var currentWidth = ui.size.width;
      
        // this accounts for padding in the panels + 
        // borders, you could calculate this using jQuery
        var padding = 12; 
      
        // this accounts for some lag in the ui.size value, if you take this away 
        // you'll get some instable behaviour
        $(this).width(currentWidth);
      
        // set the content panel width
        $("#content").width(containerWidth - currentWidth - padding);            
    }
});
```

**Update 2**: I added a minWidth and maxWidth option to my example so you can only resize the left column within these boundaries.

[UPDATED fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QkZL8/15/)

Comment: Also, the last comma should also be removed - even though some browsers ignore it, others may give a syntax error.

Comment: No problem, it may work now, but probably not the way OP expected.

Comment: Also, the panel itself should be the resize target, not some weird splitter-element in between. The handle should be at `'e'` if the left panel is being resized. Some inverse synchronous resize would have to be set up for the two panels as well, unless markup is changed radically.

Comment: Indeed David, updating my answer.

Comment: Sir, can you update my jsfiddle? I'm a beginner and sometimes I can't understand how can I do.. Thanks..
And the sliptter that david written is what I want to do but I said it is not sliplitting at the same time with me..

Comment: Okey, Still I'm waiting for you @JeroenMoons

Comment: You're welcome. Check my last edit, it makes the behaviour more stable.

Comment: Can I ask one more quest?
If I pull left panel too much to right, the content jumps bottom. Can I block this?

Comment: I have edited my example so you can only move the panel within certain bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so i made up a quick mock up if you are still lost...
so the code is...

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".resize").resizable();           
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html
        {
            margin: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            padding: 0px;

        }


        .resize
        {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            background: blue;
            cursor:pointer;         
            max-width: 300px;
            padding: 20px;
        }



    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="resize">
    <p>
       Nullam vitae eros sapien. Nulla sit amet ipsum sagittis felis lobortis imperdiet eget eu est. Pellentesque tincidunt dictum libero, vitae sagittis augue interdum ac. Nam cursus, ante eget consequat mollis, mauris justo consequat tellus, at rutrum justo dolor ut tellus. Curabitur interdum, augue a aliquam tempus, neque lectus rhoncus lorem, sed mattis velit purus eu nibh. Donec adipiscing condimentum eros ac convallis. Morbi purus felis, condimentum at rutrum nec, auctor quis mi. Sed odio turpis, blandit vitae sagittis a, accumsan rutrum risus. Sed ultricies congue quam, consectetur porttitor augue ultrices non. Mauris cursus quam sed eros fermentum scelerisque. Mauris nisi purus, iaculis ac pulvinar ac, rhoncus a est. Quisque vitae mollis lacu
    </p>
</div>
<div class="noneresize">
    <p> 
        This element is not the resizing one
    </p>
</div>



    </body>
</html>
​
```

​
This works both ways horizontal and vertically  .

**Edit**
another example

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".resize").resizable();           
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html
        {
            margin: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            padding: 0px;

        }

        .holder div
        {
            float: left;            
        }

        .resize
        {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            background: blue;
            cursor:pointer;         
            max-width: 300px;
            padding: 20px;
        }


        .holder
        {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="holder">
    <div class="resize">
        <p>
           Nullam vitae eros sapien. Nulla sit amet ipsum sagittis felis lobortis imperdiet eget eu est. Pellentesque tincidunt dictum libero, vitae sagittis augue interdum ac. Nam cursus, ante eget consequat mollis, mauris justo consequat tellus, at rutrum justo dolor ut tellus. Curabitur interdum, augue a aliquam tempus, neque lectus rhoncus lorem, sed mattis velit purus eu nibh. Donec adipiscing condimentum eros ac convallis. Morbi purus felis, condimentum at rutrum nec, auctor quis mi. Sed odio turpis, blandit vitae sagittis a, accumsan rutrum risus. Sed ultricies congue quam, consectetur porttitor augue ultrices non. Mauris cursus quam sed eros fermentum scelerisque. Mauris nisi purus, iaculis ac pulvinar ac, rhoncus a est. Quisque vitae mollis lacu
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="noneresize">
        <p> 
            This element is not the resizing one
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


    </body>
</html>
​
```

Comment: jsfiddle cant run jquery ui, so try it on your computer

Comment: I've done sir. But still not work. And I need 2 div. resizer will resize my left div. Like a splitter that @david slavik written

Comment: Ok I did it so check it again

Comment: Good, but Just I need a little help. How can I put noneresize element to right side of resizer. And noneresize will be wide or small namely will be effected from resizer. I hope I can explain. Thanks.

Comment: @iedmrc99 have you tested my other example?

Comment: How can you make them side by side. take up the browser width and have them adjust to each other?

Answer (score 2):

what about use anything completed like Kendo splitter: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/splitter/index.html

-David

Comment: Oh yes.. This is good but I want to resize div at the same time. This splitter set width after I put the splitter right or left.. Can you have an idea sir?