# Hold border and Resize two or more DIV simultaneously in the same container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, widget

Code :

```
<div id="widget1">
  <div class="part blue">this is the part</div>
  <div class="part white">of the genial</div>
  <div class="part red">and good widget</div>
</div>
```

Let's say that `div#widget1` is 99px width and `div.part` are 33px by default.

How can I easily resize `div.blue` by increasing its width and deacreasing width of other div.part proportionnaly ?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#synchronous-resize : give an example which show element increase in the same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [resizing div panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403095/resizing-div-panel)

Comment: This is what I want... Thanks Jeroen Moons ! If you copy this JS part of this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/QkZL8/15/) as an answer I will validate/accepte the answer

Comment: It's doesn't work like that, you should just upvote the answer in the other question. This will likely be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

possible duplicate of [resizing div panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403095/resizing-div-panel)

Testing my solution here : http://jsfiddle.net/lnplnp/MxKLH/

But this do perfectly what I need :

JAVASCRIPT :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // init
  var containerWidth = $("#container").width();
  var nbpanels = $(".panel").size();
  var padding = 2.5;

  $(".panel").width( (containerWidth / nbpanels) - (nbpanels * padding - 2 * padding));

  $(".panel").resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    maxWidth: 450,
    minWidth: 120,
    resize: function(event, ui){
      var currentWidth = ui.size.width;
      // set the content panel width
      $(".panel").width( ( (containerWidth - currentWidth + padding ) / (nbpanels - 1) ) - ((nbpanels - 1) * padding) );
      $(this).width(currentWidth);
    }
  });

});
```

HTML :

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="panel1" class="panel" >
    some text, lorem ipsum. some text, lorem ipsum. some text, lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div id="panel2" class="panel" >
    some more text, lorem ipsum. some text, lorem ipsum. some text, lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div id="panel3" class="panel" >
    some text, lorem ipsum. some text, lorem ipsum. some text, lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div id="panel4" class="panel" >
    some text, lorem ipsum. some text, lorem ipsum. some text, lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.clear{
  clear:both;
}

#container{
  border: 1px red solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
}

.panel{
  background-color: #9999FF;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 2.5px;
}

#panel1{
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

I think the JS can be improve... but it's working !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.part').attr('width',10);
$('.blue').attr('width',50);
```

Using this the width of all divs named part will be decreased and the width of only blue increased.

Comment: He wants interactive resizing.