# Resizing two divs side by side by a handle in the middle with js/jquery

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, user-interface

Unfortunately i don't know the correct term, but everyone has seen this functionality: there are two div containers side by side and in their middle, there is a vertical line; by dragging the line to the left, the width of left div shrinks while the width of the right div grows accordingly to the position of the handle and vice versa.
How can i accomplish this in javascript, or even better, jQuery?

As an illustration from another context, here are two screenshots of a user interface:

[image: handle dragged to the left]

[image: handle dragged to the right]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you tried that didn't work and describe the difference between what you got and what you wanted.

Comment: I didn't code anything yet, because i am not very used to javascript; i thought there might be a ready and often used solution, maybe a readymade plugin or code-snippet …

Comment: css offers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize and eventually a js fallback for older browser

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Bek9L/ (JQuery, only works for 2 columns but could get you started)

Or look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403095/resizing-div-panel

Comment: Have a look at some plugins: http://goo.gl/CmqMFK and code: http://goo.gl/awt3pu

Comment: The fiddle and the other links are great!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link for the JavaScript: http://methvin.com/splitter/

Regarding the boxes you will have on the right, you only need to use CSS.
You will need to fload left all your elements and set a min and max width:

```
.elements { float:left; max-width: 100px; min-width: 50px; }
```

Your max size needs to be double the min size not to have a weird space on the side sometimes.

Comment: So "splitter" was the term to know!