# How to create table with resizable row and columns like HTML, CSS, JS boxes on JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I've successfully created 3 view boxes using an html table. Each view can be hidden. Now I'd like to have each views width and height to be resizable, pretty much exactly like how its done in JSFiddle where each code editing box can be resized. I found a jQuery widget but it only allow for the columns to be resized and not the boxes. I also found this but it was not implemented with a table http://www.bootply.com/RwnUXIcLap . Here's what I have so far https://jsfiddle.net/3waurzbf/ .

```js
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

console.log(inputs);
console.log(tds);
var changeView = function () {

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (!inputs[i].checked) {
      if (tds[i].style.display !== 'none') tds[i].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      if(tds[i].style.display === 'none') tds[i].style.display = '';
    }
  }

  if (!inputs[0].checked && !inputs[1].checked) rows[0].style.display = 'none';
  else rows[0].style.display = '';

  if (!inputs[2].checked) rows[1].style.display = 'none';
  else rows[1].style.display = '';

};

changeView();


//$("#views-table").colResizable({liveDrag:true});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}

table td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#views-container {
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>View 1</td>

    <td>View 2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">View 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="views-container">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="changeView()"><label>View 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="changeView()"><label>View 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="changeView()"><label>View 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You may look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403095/resizing-div-panel

Comment: Using jQuery UI might help with this.  It has a [resizable feature here](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI `.resizable()`, although it's a bit tricky with table display and requires a little extra code.

Check out this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/18k3umpp/3/

I've added a couple ids to View 1 and View 2:

```
<tr>
    <td id="v1">View 1</td>

    <td id="v2">View 2</td>
</tr>
```

Then try this:

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var v1Width = $("#v1").width()


    $("#v1").resizable({
        minWidth: 50,
        maxWidth: windowWidth - 80,
        maxHeight: windowHeight * (.83),
        handles: "e, s"
    }).on("resize", function() {

        if (v1Width == $("#v1").width()) {
            $("#v2").height(0)
        }
        v1Width = $("#v1").width()
    });

    $("#v2").resizable({
        maxHeight: windowHeight * (.83),
        handles: "s"
    }).on("resize", function() {
        $("#v1").height(0)
    });

});
```

Of course you can adjust the `minWidth`,`maxWidth`, and `maxHeight` options to whatever your needs are.

Comment: @DanielKobe Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: may i know what is the significance of `handles` here in the answer ?

Comment: @PardeepJain The handles option is used to indicate which sides of the element can be grabbed for the purpose of resizing. "e" refers to east, and "s" refers to south, so the right and bottom edges of the element. http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles

Comment: ohh okay thanku so much for information, but in any case mt resizable is not working, do you know why ?